# How to use useref() to target dynamic material-ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, material-ui

I am in position where I need to upload files to a particular channel but whats happening is , it's always uploaded to 1st tab/channel.

I am trying to use useRef to achieve it but don't know exactly what is missing ?

By tab I mean [material-ui tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#simple-tabs)

Consider values of tab as 0 ,1 and 2 respectively.

I'v tried to replicate the same in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wind-j203y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**Issue**

try to add any image by clicking attach icon in tab 2 or 3 , it will be shown in tab 1.

```
  const fileRef = useRef(tab); // tab value can be 0,1 or 2

  useEffect(() => {
    setProgress(0);
  }, [file]);

  const [handleSubmit, loading] = usePromise(() =>
    onSend(text, fileKey).then(
      () => {
        setText('');
        setFile();
        setProgress(0);
        setFileKey();
      },
      (e) => snack.error(e.message),
    ),
  );

  const onFileSelect = (e) => {
    const { files } = e.target;
    const f = files[0];
    setFile(f);
    fileRef.current.value = '';

    const key = uuidv4() + '_' + f.name;
    setUploading(true);
    Storage.put(key, f, {
      progressCallback: (progress) => {
        const pc = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
        setProgress(`Uploading... ${Math.round(pc)}%`);
      },
    })
      .then((result) => {
        setFileKey(result.key);
        setUploading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setUploading(false);
        snack.error(err.message);
      });
  };


  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {file && (
        <FilePreview
          loading={uploading}
          progress={progress}
          file={file}
          onDelete={onDeleteFile}
        />
      )}
      <div className={classes.inputContainer}>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <div className={classes.upload}>
            <IconButton component="label" htmlFor="file-input">
              <AttachFileIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <input
              accept={FILE_TYPES}
              ref={fileRef}
              id="file-input"
              type="file"
              onChange={onFileSelect}
            />
          </div>
          <IconButton
            color="primary"
            disabled={loading || uploading || !(text || fileKey)}
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            <SendIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean `tab`?; And where do you init `tab` that you pass as an argument to useRef?

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy sorry, my bad , By tab I mean material ui tabs https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#simple-tabs I've updated question description. Tnx for pointing out.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, it doesn't make sense, to do it with a ref. Maybe post a little bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Adam Sure! i've added sandbox link in the description https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wind-j203y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is on this particular area:

```
<IconButton component="label" htmlFor="file-input">
  <AttachFileIcon />
</IconButton>
<input
  accept={FILE_TYPES}
  ref={fileRef}
  id="file-input"
  type="file"
  onChange={onFileSelect}
/>
```

Definition of [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) (or `htmlFor` in React)

> The id of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the
>  element. The first element in the document with an id matching
> the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label
> element, if it is a labelable element. If it is not labelable then the
> for attribute has no effect. If there are other elements which also
> match the id value, later in the document, they are not considered.

So in short, since all of the `label` are pointing to the same `id`, it will be correlated with the first instance of that `input` field which is the 1 on the first tab.

To fix this, simply pass different `htmlFor` & `id` for each tab specific components

```
<IconButton component="label" htmlFor={tab}> <-- where tab should be unique to this tab
  <AttachFileIcon />
</IconButton>
<input
  accept={FILE_TYPES}
  ref={fileRef}
  id={tab} <-- where tab should be unique to this tab
  type="file"
  onChange={onFileSelect}
/>
```

[image: Edit confident-bird-nptc2]

Comment: strangely, same thing isn' working in my sandbox. have you done any other changes too ?

Comment: yeah the `tab` should be unique so on your `Array.map` back on `App` component, I instead pass `idx` to `tab` prop